# Sampledata migration

Tags: pentaho

In a fresh install of the biserver, after you migrate the solution databases to, say, mysql, is there any quick way to import both the demo objects (dashboards, reports, and so on) into the jcr repository, along with the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Go to /pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/default-content and delete the dates that are appended to all those files. So, instead of

> plugin-samples.zip.201811161017

for example, make it so that it's

> plugin-samples.zip

as the name. Turn it back into a zip file. Restart the server, and all the default content will be loaded automatically into jcr. You'll notice if you go back after restarting the server that the zip files will have been renamed with the date of when you restarted the server.